# VBA - Swapping cells until condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and have trouble with swapping cells through a conditional loop.

I have a table which looks like

[image]

and want to transform it (move numeric cells to column b and remove non-numeric values) into

[image]

Right now I have the code

```
Sub Swap()

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     For j = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         If IsNumeric(.Cells(j, 2)) = False Then
             For k = 2 To .Cells(j, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns
                 Do Until IsNumeric(.Cells(j, 2)) = True
                     t = .Cells(j, k)
                     .Cells(j, k) = .Cells(j, k + 1)
                     .Cells(j, k + 1) = t
                 Loop
             Next k
         Else
         End If
     Next j
 End With
End Sub
```

which works fine until line 9, where it keeps swaping B9 and C9 in an endless loop.

I hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conditional Loop

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Swap()

    Dim rg As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim lCell As Range
        Dim lRow As Long
        With .UsedRange
            Set lCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            lRow = lCell.Row
            Set lCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        End With
        Set rg = .Range("B1", .Cells(lRow, lCell.Column))
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim NumberFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            cValue = Data(r, c)
            If VarType(cValue) = vbDouble Then
                NumberFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
        If NumberFound Then
            Data(r, 1) = cValue
            NumberFound = False
        Else
            Data(r, 1) = Empty ' no number found
        End If
        For c = 2 To cCount
            Data(r, c) = Empty
        Next c
    Next r
    
    rg.Value = Data

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

…  It's doing **exactly** what you *told* it to.

You have a `Do Until` check on B9, where you swap it with cell C9.  So, it starts as "ee", and you swap them.  Now it is "e", so you swap them.  It's "ee" again, so it swaps them again.  Repeat ad nauseum

You need to rethink that `Do Until`.  A crude Brute Force approach would be to `Delete` the cell with the "shift left" parameter.  Another method would be to put the `For k = 2..` loop *inside* the `Do Until` loop, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

When the algorithm Arive to 9's row it fall in loop because cell 2 and 3 both are unumeric (e, ee) and you're swapping them to infinity...
Its better to do this steps for each row:
1- iterate all over the row's cells to find numeric one and copy that
2- clean all not needed cells and make them blank
3- fill second cell of row by copied number
4- done!

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses Excel's MAX function, since it will happily ignore any non-numeric data in the range and simply return the (single) numeric datum (to the variable *number*):

```
Sub unConditional()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, number As Long, dataRow As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            Set dataRow = .Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, .Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Column - 1)
            number = WorksheetFunction.Max(dataRow)
            dataRow.ClearContents
            .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = number
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).